# What is the best way to create SharePoint 2010 copy?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, replication

I'm looking for a way to duplicate the content of a SharePoint 2010 server in order to work against it without taxing the main (production) server.  I would need the backup server to update as needed, but I'm not looking for a failover solution.  It looks like 2010 includes replication features for failover, but I can't tell if this is appropriate for my solution as well (simply not configuring the switchover feature).  Can someone with SP 2010 experience tell me if this feature would work for my needs?

Comment: Well first please define your needs. What exactly 'work against it' mean?

Answer (score 3):

You could attach a restored backup of your production content database.  See this MSDN documentation for more info: [Attach or detach content databases (Sharepoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628582.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There is also a GUI tool http://sushi.codeplex.com/ which should help you. You could backup production and restore to dev site whenever you needed to.

You could also use either stsadm.exe and the backup/restore option OR the powershell cmd backup/restore.

In addition, there is a built in interface in Central Admin to backup/restore sites. I've generally found either the command line or the SUSHI tool to be quicker and easier.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the taxing work is on the sharepoint side, not the SQL side. You could attach another front end to the farm but reserve it for only your traffic. Otherwise you're looking at some form of backup/restore to copy everything to a 2nd duplicate farm.